# Cumulative sum column in mysql - set function not working

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a table to show weekly spend of users and show the running total for the month to compare against targets.

I've tried two different variants of `set @csm :=0` but neither seem to be working but I can't seem to find an alternative solution.

I also tried to group the case when slightly differently:

```
when day(date) BETWEEN 0 AND 15 then 'Week_2'
```

But this didn't seem to work either, I'd appreciate some clarity as to why this didn't work for the creating a running total!

The code I'm trying to use now looks like this:

```
select
    case
        when day(date) < 8 then 'Week_1'
        when day(date) < 15 then 'Week_2'
        when day(date) < 22 then 'Week_3'
        when day(date) < 29 then 'Week_4'
    else 'Week_5'
    end as Week_Num,
    sum(case when status = 'Complete' then charged_amount else 0 end) as Charged,
    (@csm:= @csm + sum(case when status = 'Complete' then charged_amount else 0 end)) as cumulative
from
    my_table 
where
    DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y-%m')
group by 1
```

But I have another version that starts off with:

```
select
    my_table.Week_Num,
    my_table.Charged,
    (@runtot := @runtot + my_table.Charged) as mtd
```

But that didn't work either.

I'm looking to have a table showing the `Week_Num`, the `Charged` amount for that week and then the `Cumulative` sum for the month to date:

```
Week_Num || Charged || Cumulative
Week_1   || 1       || 1
Week_2   || 2       || 3
Week_3   || 3       || 6
Week_4   || 4       || 10
Week_5   || 5       || 15
```

---

Based on  Tim Biegeleisen's response, the code now looks like:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN (DAY(date) - 1) / 7 < 1 THEN 'Week_1'
         WHEN (DAY(date) - 1) / 7 < 2 THEN 'Week_2'
         WHEN (DAY(date) - 1) / 7 < 3 THEN 'Week_3'
         WHEN (DAY(date) - 1) / 7 < 4 THEN 'Week_4'
         ELSE 'Week_5' END AS Week_Num,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'Complete' THEN charged_amount ELSE 0 END) AS Charged,
    (SELECT 
        SUM(CASE WHEN mt2.status = 'Complete' THEN mt2.charged_amount ELSE 0 END)
    FROM my_table mt2
        WHERE 
            (DAY(mt2.date) - 1) / 7 <= (DAY(mt1.date) - 1) / 7
        and 
            DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m')) AS Cumulative
FROM my_table mt1
WHERE
    DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m')
GROUP BY
    1
ORDER BY
    1
```

The table should look like this:

```
Week_Num || Charged || Cumulative
Week_1   || 4526    || 4526
Week_2   || 45093   || 49619
Week_3   || 38869   || 88488
Week_4   || 123987  || 212475
Week_5   || 7920    || 220389
```

What is actually looks like is:

```
Week_Num || Charged || Cumulative
Week_1   || 4526    || 3835
Week_2   || 45093   || 7733
Week_3   || 38869   || 88488
Week_4   || 123987  || 174355
Week_5   || 7920    || 218228
```

It's potentially a coincidence, but confused why `Week_3` is spot on and the final cumulation is only roughly 2000 off.

Sample Data:

```
Payment_ID || date       || Charged_Amount || Status
000001     || 2019-06-01 || 4526           || Complete
000002     || 2019-06-08 || 45093          || Complete
000003     || 2019-06-15 || 38869          || Complete
000004     || 2019-06-22 || 123987         || Complete
000005     || 2019-06-29 || 7920           || Complete
```

Comment: You are aggregating by each week of the current month, so how can you expect a cumulative sum to the current _date_ ?

Comment: Well that was were I thought the other way of aggregating - `when day(date) BETWEEN 0 AND 15 then 'Week_2'` - would come in as it would sum everything in that range (including the prior week), but that didn't work either. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: You might want to include your expected output, so that your requirements are completely clear.

Comment: something like that ^

Comment: I posted an answer below, I'm happy to iterate with you to get it right.I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would phrase your query by diviidng the day number by 7 to detect the week:

```
SELECT
    CASE Week_Num WHEN 0 THEN 'Week_1'
                         WHEN 1 THEN 'Week_2'
                         WHEN 2 THEN 'Week_3'
                         WHEN 3 THEN 'Week_4'
                                ELSE 'Week_5' END AS Week_Num,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'Complete' THEN charged_amount ELSE 0 END) AS Charged,
    (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN mt2.status = 'Complete' THEN mt2.charged_amount ELSE 0 END)
     FROM my_table mt2
     WHERE (DAY(mt2.date) - 1) / 7 <= mt1.Week_Num) AS Cumulative
FROM
(
    SELECT *, (DAY(date) - 1) / 7 AS Week_Num
    FROM my_table
) mt1
WHERE
    DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m')
GROUP BY
    Week_Num
ORDER BY
    Week_Num;
```

### Demo

Comment: I've restructured the code a bit a the grouping was messing up a bit and so I can better read the case when. It's now kind of working but isn't summing the Charged table properly. I've added what the code now looks like above and the result its giving me

Comment: Without sample data I'm afraid what I wrote above is the most help I can offer.  If you can setup a demo using my query with your data, I can take a closer look.

Comment: Let me know if what I've added about helps at all. Alternatively, let me know how to set up a sample data and I will. Appreciate your help.

Comment: It doesn't help.  You've only shown _output_, but what we need is _input_.

Comment: I made an update based on your sample data, and I gave a demo link.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. Appreciate it was hard work!